# Why has my comparator stopped working?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, comparator

I have a method that looks like this to add and sort:

```
  @Override
  public boolean add( Object o )
  {       
  boolean contains = false;
  for (Object : this) {       
      if (o1.getNum().equals(o.getNum())) {
          o = o1;
          contains = true;
          break;
      } 
  }

  if (contains) { 
      // merges
  } else {
      return //add;
  }

// Sorts ArrayList from highest to lowest product number   
    Collections.sort(this, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Integer f = // get number;
            Integer s = // get number;
            if (f == s) {
                return 0;
            } else
            return f>s ? 1 : -1;
        }
   });


return true;
}

}
```

On it's own without any other code, collections.sort works perfectly. However, after adding in the first part, it has stopped working. Any ideas how to get it working again?

Comment: "after adding in the first part" <- What part would that be exactly? And how has it stopped working? Do you get an Exception or a result you don't expect?

Comment: Hint: integer has a static compare method that nicely compares int values. Better use that. And use intValue() instead of having the compiler turn integer objects into int values repeatedly.

Comment: Then: you want us to spend our time to help you with your problem so you please spend the time required to properly format indent all of your code. And from a design standpoint it is simply horrible to retrieve the product number as string to then parse that as number like this. Are you sure for all eternity that product numbers are numbers as strings? If so - why are you representing numbers using strings?

Comment: You are comparing `Integer` objects by identity instead of value when you do `if (f == s)`. That's not what you want. Why not use `int`?

Comment: You are only sorting when the entry is already in the list. It won't be sorted if you add a new entry.

Answer (score 0):

If a value resulting from a product is not an integer, will Integer.parseInt throw a NumberFormatException?

Comment: There are various ways how this code could go wrong. It could also throw null pointer exceptions. You are really not answering the question.

Comment: You are correct in that there could be problems other than parse error but we have no details about the problem.

Comment: Should I delete my answer to avoid encouraging low quality questions?

Answer (score 0):

I moved my code and placed collection.sort right after return //add;